# Information about created and deleted instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

Good afternoon friends.

I have a question about the GCP Logging environment.

I need to survey within a year the instances that have been created and deleted, instances that have undergone changes in their configuration, etc.

Would it be possible to know this information in a logging file or Google Cloud service?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You van use following advance filter:

to trace instance creation use:

```
protoPayload.response.operationType="insert"
timestamp>="2019-08-20T20:37:36.000Z" timestamp<="2020-08-20T21:37:36.776Z"
```

to trace instance deletion use:

```
jsonPayload.event_subtype="compute.instances.delete" 
timestamp>="2019-08-20T20:37:36.000Z" timestamp<="2020-08-20T21:37:36.776Z"
```

To trace the instances that their machimetype have been changed:

```
resource.type="gce_instance" 
jsonPayload.event_type="GCE_OPERATION_DONE"
jsonPayload.event_subtype="compute.instances.setMachineType"
```

Please note, you have access to last 400 days of records. If you want to keep them longer, you have to export audit log entries outside of Logging by creating a logs sink.[1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query [1] to know the number of instances created and [2] for number of instances deleted during a given time frame. Further, you have the flexibility to adjust the time frame as per your requirements on the GCP UI.

[1]:

```
protoPayload.methodName:"compute.instances.insert"
operation.last="true"
severity!=ERROR
```

[2]:

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
protoPayload.methodName:"compute.instances.delete"
severity!=ERROR
```